# How to detect whether Windows is shutting down/starting?

Tags: c#, windows, startup, detect, shutdown

I need to execute 2 SSH commands using the SSH.NET library. First command will be executed when Windows starting up and the second command when windows shutting down. How can i accomplish that?

Comment: Start-up is easy, you can just set your application to run on start-up. Shutdown involves monitoring the `SystemEvents.SessionEnding` event, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the shutdown or prompt user to confirm shutting down then you can use [SystemEvents.SessionEnding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx). Otherwise to perform any task without interrupting shut down use [SystemEvents.SessionEnded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx)

And for starting up, set your application as one of the startup applications.

Comment: Thanks i need the SessionEnded. Do you know if its better to make my application to work as a service?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve actually.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the `Task-Scheduler`.
If you just want to make a very simple application which only fires two commands i would not mess around with a service...

Your benefit would be to catch the windows-startup.

Just write a `console application` and `handle command args`.

One for shutdown and one for startup